# scrape page using HTML elements

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am just starting out with Python and trying to scrape track listings for one of my favourite radio stations.

I have managed to get as far as obtaining the track titles, the initial problem I have is that the artist and track are on seperate lines.  What I need is for this to be on a single line.

Im also trying to obtain the song time (08:52) from the span but can't a way to get just the innner text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raddio.net/112842-loversrock-radio/playlist/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

station = soup.find("h1")
print(station.text.strip())

all_tracks = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "title")
#print(all_tracks).text

for track in all_tracks:
    individual_track_data = track.text.strip()
    print(individual_track_data)
```

Artist and track need to be on same line.

```
<div class="title"><b>Beres Hammond</b>
                    - Settling Down                </div>
```

Trying to get track played time.

```
<span data-name="translated-song-time" data-time="2023-10-28 07:52">**08:52**</span>
```

The below is the end goal which I want to show in a Pandas data frame.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83kQk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
station = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
all_tracks = soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'item'})

tracks = []
for track in all_tracks:
    try:
        artist, title = track.find('div', attrs={'class': 'title'}).text.split('\n')
        title = title[title.index('-')+1:].strip()
        played_time = pd.Timestamp(track.find('span')['data-time'], tz='UTC')
        tracks.append([station, artist, title, played_time])
    except ValueError:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame(tracks, columns=['Station', 'Artist', 'Track', 'Played Time'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                      Station             Artist                  Track               Played Time
0    Playlist LoversrockRadio       Sylvia Tella          Plastic Smile 2023-10-28 08:36:00+00:00
1    Playlist LoversrockRadio  01.Latoya Jackson        Camp Kutchi Kai 2023-10-28 08:31:00+00:00
2    Playlist LoversrockRadio     Gregory Isaacs               Margaret 2023-10-28 08:27:00+00:00
3    Playlist LoversrockRadio       Jerry Harris       New Love For You 2023-10-28 08:24:00+00:00
4    Playlist LoversrockRadio        Gappy Ranks    Heaven In Your Eyes 2023-10-28 08:21:00+00:00
..                        ...                ...                    ...                       ...
118  Playlist LoversrockRadio      Beres Hammond          Settling Down 2023-10-28 00:16:00+00:00
119  Playlist LoversrockRadio            Gyptain  You're The Best Thing 2023-10-28 00:12:00+00:00
120  Playlist LoversrockRadio       Jerry Harris       New Love For You 2023-10-28 00:09:00+00:00
121  Playlist LoversrockRadio    Everton Blender      Lift Up Your Head 2023-10-28 00:04:00+00:00
122  Playlist LoversrockRadio       Sugar Minott       Make It With You 2023-10-28 00:00:00+00:00

[123 rows x 4 columns]
```

Note:

1. You have to clean `artist` if needed
2. The `played_time` is set to UTC. You have to convert it in your local timezone.

Something like:

```
>>> df['Played Time'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris').dt.strftime('%-H:%M')
0      10:36
1      10:31
2      10:27
3      10:24
4      10:21
       ...  
118     2:16
119     2:12
120     2:09
121     2:04
122     2:00
Name: Played Time, Length: 123, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this getting an error on this line.  title = title[row[1].index('-')+1:].strip()       NameError: name 'row' is not defined.

Comment: @TriggerThumb. Sorry. I fixed my answer. Can you check it please?